# Android remove desktop shortcut

Tags: android

How can I make an android application remove it's desktop shortcut when the user deletes the application?
How can I make an android application that does this automatically?

Comment: I think this is the default behaviour. If you delete the application android delete everything related to it: db, datas, shortcuts and so on :)

Comment: no its not working like that , its not deleting by default , so do u know any code that do delete the shortcut.
Thank You In Advance

Comment: Which launcher are you using? On the default launcher (and any other launcher I know of) the shortcuts are removed when an application is removed from the phone. Are you sure you are actually removing the application?

Comment: It's impossible that when you **disinstall** an app from your phone the desktop icon remains (or icons in general)

Comment: @FuzzicalLogic you're right. Just undid my downvote.

Answer (score 1):

Steevoo,

To remove a desktop icon programmatically, or even whether you need to depends on the launcher you are using. Some launchers allow you to add and remove icons programmatically. Some do all of that by themselves. Some even require you to do it manually. And even fewer may require a reboot to reanalyze the applications installed on the phone. In short, there is not a clear answer, especially since there is no default launcher; there are just default launchers for particular phones.

Comment: i use this code to add shortcut to the desktop :

Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        shortcutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        shortcutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        final Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent)
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, "myShortcut");
        intent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
so how can i delete this shortcut when user delete main application

thanks for reply

Comment: Yes, that is the way to add a shortcut (if the launcher accepts it, which is not guaranteed). This does not indicate or even hint at a UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT.

Comment: so how the others applications can do that ? like skype

Comment: Often, other applications do NOT do that. The launcher has a receiver for OnPackagedRemoved and it removes the shortcut. However, this is up to the launcher in many cases. The general feeling is that the USER should decide what is on and off of their own screens.

Comment: IF a given launcher does have that capability, it may be programmed for, however, it is not currently a standardized implementation, and many do not see a need. Since each phone uses a different launcher (in most cases), currently there is no way to do it without programming for a specific launcher in mind. This is how many Widgets are made to begin with because different launchers support different widget capbilities (such as scrollable widgets).